# What is he fishing for?

Tags: chinese

Is there a story behind this painting of a man fishing in the air off the side of mountain?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Chinese, not Japanese.

The handwriting is too squiggly for me to read the middle characters but I think it says:

高山 High Mountain
??  ??
三石 Three Rocks

Searching by these characters I found other renderings with the same artist seal signature:

[image]

[This page](https://www.orientaloutpost.com/go-fishing-in-the-mountains-chinese-philosophy-painting.php) had the following explanation:

> Maybe it seems silly to go fishing in the mountains, but we all need a
> place to get away and think.
>
> In this painting the man does not expect to catch fish, but rather is
> there to think and contemplate his life, or find solutions to any
> problems he might have, and just get away from the real world for a
> while.
>
> This painting is inspired by the story of a gifted philosopher and
> scholarly man named Yan Zi Ling who was called to service by Emperor
> Liu Che during the Han Dynasty. Yan Zi Ling did not want to take a
> position of authority in the government, fearing that holding such
> power, he would become corrupt.
>
> Even though he was a wise, talented, and honorable man, he knew that
> service in the imperial court could corrupt even the most ethical
> person. He felt so strongly about preserving his own integrity and
> dignity that he decided that it would be better to live in exile than
> to become another corrupt official.
>
> For several years, Emperor Liu Che sent men out to search the
> countryside and find Yan Zi Ling. But the emperor's men couldn't find
> him. Of course, the emperor's men had no idea that Yan Zi Ling now
> lives in his own special place in the mountains where he could get
> away from the trouble of the world.
>
> We all need a place to get away from it all and this man has found his
> place. Perhaps this painting will inspire you to find yours?

Probably inspired by the original painting "[AFTER LIU SONGNIAN (1150-1225)](https://www.bonhams.com/auctions/20580/lot/349/)"